# How to fill html textarea element with playwright-java?

Tags: java, playwright

I have a textarea html tag element and need to update the text within it. For example, here is what the tag looks like:

```html
<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea>
```

Question: how can I add a string inside of the textarea html tag? For example, I would like to add "hello" in the html tag and make it look like this afterwards:

```html
<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;">hello</textarea>
```

I have tried this code:

```
page.fill(".g-recaptcha-response", "hello");
```

However, it throws this error: "waiting for selector .g-recaptcha-response. selector resolved to hidden <textarea id="g-recaptcharesponse" name="g-recaptcha-response...> elementHandle.fill("hello") waiting for element to be visible, enabled and editable, element is not visible - waiting...

Comment: The log is saying that the element is not visible.

Answer (score 3):

Playwright has something called `Auto-waiting/Actionability` by default.

https://playwright.dev/java/docs/actionability

In that case the `fill` method is waiting for the textarea to be visible, but since that element is always invisible, it throws an exception after some time.

You could try to set the `force` tag to *true* in order to ignore those actionabilities, but honestly it didn't work for me:

```
page.locator("#g-recaptcha-response").fill(solution, new Page.FillOptions().setForce(true));
```

What I ended up doing was executing a Javascript code through `evaluate`:

```
page.evaluate("solution => document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response').innerHTML = solution", "hello");
```

PS: I translated the code above from C# to Java, so I didn't tested it, but it'll probably work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `#` when the locator is an ID: `page.fill("#g-recaptcha-response", "hello");`

`.` is for classes

See #id selector: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp

and .class selector: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp